# Alternatives to \sideset and \nolimits?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, subscripts

I'm trying to typeset

[image: $one \sideset{}{_{three}}\prod two$]

as `$one \sideset{}{_{three}}\prod two$` in instiki (well, ok, it's the nLab [waves to Andrew Stacey]), but it doesn't work. Is there any other alternative to `\sideset` that I could use?

Comment: The `\fourIdx` command from the [fouridx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fouridx) package could be an option; no idea if it works in instiki, though.

Comment: I've also tried `\nolimits` to no avail

Comment: @David: This site doesn't have math-tex, since most of the time we're discussing the TeX itself, not the math.  I took the liberty of embedding the desired image in your question.

Comment: not sure why you're using `\sideset`.  the following gives the same result as what is shown in the question: `$one \displaystyle\prod\nolimits_{three} two$ and if there's something else in the math string that you don't want in `\displaystyle`, just wrap the middle section in `{...}` to localize it.

Comment: @barbara - see my comment above (number 2 in the list)

Comment: @David -- i know you said that `\nolimits` didn't work.  but i tested the answer i gave (with `\documentclass{article})` and it does.  so the result you are getting must depend on the document class or some package that you didn't identify. (neither instiki nor nLab appears in the ctan list, and i'm not familiar with them.) with additional information about your preamble, it should be possible to determine what's really happening.

Comment: For those that don't know: Instiki is a wiki designed specifically to be suitable for mathematics.  For that, it uses a program called _iTeX_ to convert a subset of LaTeX to MathML.  The nLab is a project that uses Instiki.  Relevant links: [instiki](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/wiki/instiki/show/HomePage), [itexToMML](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/~distler/blog/itex2MML.html), and [nLab](http://ncatlab.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*waves back*

This is probably off-topic (as iTeX is only based on a subset of TeX, not a TeX package or format), but there is an answer that is similar to a LaTeX solution which is to use the `\tensor` command.  In LaTeX this is supplied by the [`tensor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tensor) package.  In iTeX, it is one of the implemented commands.

```
$one \tensor{\prod}{_three} two$
```

Produces:

[image: tensor command in Instiki]

(I missed this first time around, sorry.  Happened to search for `instiki` here and spotted this.  Probably better posted on the nForum.)

Comment: Thanks! I have been slack at looking at SEv2 sites so missed your response. Now I can't remember where I was doing this!